# Encoding JSON as Base64 Before HTTP POSTing It (in Haskell)

Tags: json, http, haskell

**Problem:** I am attempting to POST some JSON to an HTTP endpoint that *only accepts Base64 encoding*.

**Code Sample:** Here is a code sample which successfully posts *without* Base64 encoding:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib where

import           Data.Aeson                 (encode, object, (.=))
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import           Network.HTTP.Client
import           Network.HTTP.Client.TLS
import           Network.HTTP.Types.Status  (statusCode)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64 as B64

postJSON :: IO ()
postJSON = do
    manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings

    -- Nested JSON object to POST:
    let requestObject = object
            [ "event" .= ("App launched." :: String)
            , "properties"  .=  object [  "distinct_id" .= ("user" :: String)
                                       ,  "token"       .= ("f793bae9548d8e123cef251fd81df487" :: String)
                                       ]
            ]  
    initialRequest <- parseRequest "http://api.mixpanel.com/track"
    let request = initialRequest
            { method = "POST"
            , requestBody = RequestBodyLBS $ encode requestObject
            , requestHeaders =
                [ ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                ]
            }

    response <- httpLbs request manager
    putStrLn $ "The status code was: "
            ++ show (statusCode $ responseStatus response)
    L8.putStrLn $ responseBody response
```

**Attempt:** In order to send the JSON as Base64 encoded, I tried replacing `requestBody = RequestBodyLBS $ encode requestObject` with `requestBody = RequestBodyLBS $ Data.Bytestring.Base64.encode (encode requestObject)`, but I get a type error. So how do I encode the JSON as Base64 for this HTTP POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two things to add to jberryman's answer.

First, if (as it now appears) you're going to be putting this in a query string, you need to make sure you don't just use a base64 encoded bytestring, but instead use a base64 *url-encoded* bytestring. So don't use `Data.Bytestring.Base64` (as jberryman linked to), but rather `Data.Bytestring.Base64.URL` ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64-URL.html)).

Second, while he pointed you in the right direction on the Base64 encoding part, it seems you're still hung up on setting the querystring. For that, you should check out the `setQueryString` function in the `http-client` library you're already using (link [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:setQueryString)).

That function has the signature:

```
setQueryString :: [(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)] -> Request -> Request
```

So if you're base64 encoded bytestring is built like this

```
let urlEncodedBytestring = Data.Bytestring.Base64.URL.encode . L8.toStrict $ encode requestObject
```

and if you're attemtping to set the `data` key in the querystring of your request, then you'll probably want:

```
let requestWithQueryStringSet = setQueryString [("data", (Just urlEncodedBytestring))] request
```

Answer (score 3):

`B64.encode` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64.html) is a function from strict `ByteString` to strict `ByteString` (you'll need to hover over the type name in the haddocks to see this if you're just browsing), while `Aeson.encode` returns a lazy bytestring (from the `Data.ByteString.Lazy` module). These are two distinct types although they have the same name.

You probably have to do something like:

```
   ...
   requestBody = RequestBodyLBS $ L8.fromStrict $ Data.Bytestring.Base64.encode (L8.toStrict $ encode requestObject)
```

Comment: This compiled without error; however, my JSON POSTing still isn't being accepted by the host. It's unclear if it's related to this issue or something else entirely.

Comment: The issue is that the JSON isn't being attached to the `data`query paramater to the endpoint URL, so that it shows up as `http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=<...encoded JSON here...>`. Am reading the docs to figure out that issue but I think you solved the B64 encoding issue.

Comment: Ah so you don't want it in the body of the post, but in the querystring